# URLClassLoader problems

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a folder full of classes on which I want to load.

[image: Folder]

My `URLClassLoader` seems to load every other class just fine, but sometimes it misbehaves for some reason and it is driving me nuts. All the classes listed in the folder are basically empty (No constructors, fields, methods) and belong to their own package.

```
package death;
public class Death{

}

package death;
public class Awesome{

}

package abc.dfg.hijk;
public class Test {

}

package mesa;
public class ZZ{

}
```

I have a mechanism that extracts the package on which a class is part of, as printed out on the console.

[image: Console Output]

This is the code Im using to load each class

```
    String fileName = file.getName();

    if (fileName.contains(".class")) {

        URL[] urls = new URL[]{ classesFolder.toURI().toURL() };
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

        String packageName = getPackage(file);

        //substring -6 because of .class
        Class clazz = loader.loadClass(packageName + fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 6));

        loader.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Done loading " + file.getName());
    System.out.println("");
```

I aint exactly sure whats going on here, though I feel like Im definitely missing something, as all the other classes seem to load just fine. The value of `packageName` is correct for all the classes that were loaded. Any idea of what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't the classes in directories as per their package names? If you did that properly, you would only need *one* `URLClassLoader`, with the head of the package directory as its URL.

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace as text instead of an image.